# Python - Using BeautifulSoup to scrape an ESPN table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the "Season Stats" table on [this](http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=224165&seasonId=2017) page. Is there any way I can get the entire table into one soup object? Currently my code is like this:

```
seasonStats = soup.find('table', {'id': 'statsTable'})
categoryList = seasonStats.findAll('tr')[2].findAll('a')
```

The problem I'm running into is that FG%, FT%, 3PM, REB, AST, STL, BLK, TO, PTS are stored on one row, but RK, LAST, MOVES are stored in another row. Is there anyway I can scrape the whole table properly, where RK, TEAM, FG%, FT%, 3PM, REB, AST, STL, BLK, TO, PTS, LAST, MOVES are all stored on one row (categoryList)? It seems silly that ESPN even put these values on different rows. Moreover, if I could get this whole table into one matrix, it would be immensely help.

Desired Output:

```
['RK', 'TEAM', 'FG%', 'FT%', '3PM', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TO', 'PTS', 'LAST', 'MOVES']
['1', 'Team Li', '.4656', '.8049', '437', '1752', '962', '284', '228', '578', '4804', '4-4-1', '12']
['2', 'Team Aguilar', '.4499', '.7727', '415', '1925', '737', '276', '292', '543', '4901', '4-4-1', '0']
['3', 'Suck MyDirk', '.4533', '.8083', '410', '1798', '1035', '367', '153', '658', '5331', '3-6-0', '8']
['4', 'Knicks Tape', '.4589', '.8057', '339', '1458', '1029', '285', '132', '566', '4304', '4-5-0', '12']
['5', 'Kris Kaman  His Pants', '.4576', '.8068', '534', '1530', '940', '306', '115', '515', '4603', '5-4-0', '17']
['6', 'Nutz Vs. Draymond Green', '.4518', '.8000', '404', '1641', '1004', '270', '176', '620', '4554', '5-4-0', '12']
['7', 'Team Keyrouze', '.4548', '.7895', '441', '1558', '809', '293', '195', '510', '4874', '4-5-0', '11']
['8', 'In Porzingod We Trust', '.4607', '.7542', '275', '1699', '1020', '274', '252', '482', '4119', '6-3-0', '13']
['9', 'Team Iannetta', '.4706', '.7908', '260', '1800', '1026', '310', '137', '646', '4909', '8-1-0', '13']
['10', "Jesse's Blue Balls", '.4646', '.6766', '403', '2029', '505', '243', '238', '481', '3929', '5-4-0', '16']
['11', 'Team Pauls 2 da Wall', '.4531', '.7602', '313', '1797', '1197', '313', '268', '525', '3719', '6-3-0', '13']
['12', 'YOU REACH, I TEACH', '.4552', '.7591', '401', '1488', '997', '285', '108', '521', '3694', '4-5-0', '12']
['13', 'Team Noey', '.4740', '.7610', '273', '1821', '681', '301', '226', '491', '4059', '3-6-0', '9']
['14', 'Team Jackson', '.4325', '.7484', '206', '1104', '714', '174', '101', '383', '2532', '1-8-0', '4']
```

Current Output:

```
['1', 'Team Li', '.4656', '.8049', '437', '1752', '962', '284', '228', '578', '4804', '4-4-1', '12']
['2', 'Team Aguilar', '.4499', '.7727', '415', '1925', '737', '276', '292', '543', '4901', '4-4-1', '0']
['3', 'Suck MyDirk', '.4533', '.8083', '410', '1798', '1035', '367', '153', '658', '5331', '3-6-0', '8']
['4', 'Knicks Tape', '.4589', '.8057', '339', '1458', '1029', '285', '132', '566', '4304', '4-5-0', '12']
['5', 'Kris Kaman  His Pants', '.4576', '.8068', '534', '1530', '940', '306', '115', '515', '4603', '5-4-0', '17']
['6', 'Nutz Vs. Draymond Green', '.4518', '.8000', '404', '1641', '1004', '270', '176', '620', '4554', '5-4-0', '12']
['7', 'Team Keyrouze', '.4548', '.7895', '441', '1558', '809', '293', '195', '510', '4874', '4-5-0', '11']
['8', 'In Porzingod We Trust', '.4607', '.7542', '275', '1699', '1020', '274', '252', '482', '4119', '6-3-0', '13']
['9', 'Team Iannetta', '.4706', '.7908', '260', '1800', '1026', '310', '137', '646', '4909', '8-1-0', '13']
['10', "Jesse's Blue Balls", '.4646', '.6766', '403', '2029', '505', '243', '238', '481', '3929', '5-4-0', '16']
['11', 'Team Pauls 2 da Wall', '.4531', '.7602', '313', '1797', '1197', '313', '268', '525', '3719', '6-3-0', '13']
['12', 'YOU REACH, I TEACH', '.4552', '.7591', '401', '1488', '997', '285', '108', '521', '3694', '4-5-0', '12']
['13', 'Team Noey', '.4740', '.7610', '273', '1821', '681', '301', '226', '491', '4059', '3-6-0', '9']
['14', 'Team Jackson', '.4325', '.7484', '206', '1104', '714', '174', '101', '383', '2532', '1-8-0', '4']
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken.  All the data for one team looks like it is in the same `tr`.  Here is the first one, with all styling removed:

```
<tr>
  <td id="sovrRk_9">1</td>
  <td><a title="Team Li (Royce Li)" href="...">Team Li</a></td>
  <td><spacer type="block" width="1" height="1"> </spacer>
  </td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_19">.4656</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_20">.8049</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_17">437</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_6">1752</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_3">962</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_2">284</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_1">228</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_11">578</td>
  <td id="tmTotalStat_9_0">4804</td>
  <td>4-4-1</td>
  <td  title="Season Moves">12</td>
</tr>
```

Everything is there.

Comment: Hi, you are correct that all the data for a team is in one row. However, the headers/column names themselves are not on one row.

Comment: @wcrasta -- why do you want to scrape constant data?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, bs4
url = 'http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=224165&seasonId=2017'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find(id="statsTable")
rows = table.find_all(class_=["tableBody sortableRow","tableSubHead"])

rows = iter(rows)
header_1 = [td.text for td in next(rows).find_all('td') if td.text]
header_2 = [td.text for td in next(rows).find_all('td') if td.text]
header = header_1[:2] + header_2 + header_1[-2:]
print(header)
for row in rows:
    data = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td') if td.text]
    print(data)
```

out:

```
['RK', 'TEAM', 'FG%', 'FT%', '3PM', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TO', 'PTS', 'LAST', 'MOVES']
['1', 'Team Li', '.4656', '.8049', '437', '1752', '962', '284', '228', '578', '4804', '4-4-1', '12']
['2', 'Team Aguilar', '.4499', '.7727', '415', '1925', '737', '276', '292', '543', '4901', '4-4-1', '0']
['3', 'Suck MyDirk', '.4533', '.8083', '410', '1798', '1035', '367', '153', '658', '5331', '3-6-0', '8']
['4', 'Knicks Tape', '.4589', '.8057', '339', '1458', '1029', '285', '132', '566', '4304', '4-5-0', '12']
['5', 'Kris Kaman  His Pants', '.4576', '.8068', '534', '1530', '940', '306', '115', '515', '4603', '5-4-0', '17']
['6', 'Nutz Vs. Draymond Green', '.4518', '.8000', '404', '1641', '1004', '270', '176', '620', '4554', '5-4-0', '12']
['7', 'Team Keyrouze', '.4548', '.7895', '441', '1558', '809', '293', '195', '510', '4874', '4-5-0', '11']
['8', 'In Porzingod We Trust', '.4607', '.7542', '275', '1699', '1020', '274', '252', '482', '4119', '6-3-0', '13']
['9', 'Team Iannetta', '.4706', '.7908', '260', '1800', '1026', '310', '137', '646', '4909', '8-1-0', '13']
['10', "Jesse's Blue Balls", '.4646', '.6766', '403', '2029', '505', '243', '238', '481', '3929', '5-4-0', '17']
['11', 'Team Pauls 2 da Wall', '.4531', '.7602', '313', '1797', '1197', '313', '268', '525', '3719', '6-3-0', '13']
['12', 'YOU REACH, I TEACH', '.4552', '.7591', '401', '1488', '997', '285', '108', '521', '3694', '4-5-0', '12']
['13', 'Team Noey', '.4740', '.7610', '273', '1821', '681', '301', '226', '491', '4059', '3-6-0', '9']
['14', 'Team Jackson', '.4325', '.7484', '206', '1104', '714', '174', '101', '383', '2532', '1-8-0', '4']
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to get that matrix too. Is it possible, however, to have a row for the column names in the matrix?

Comment: you mean before row1, you need a list contain the table's header?

Comment: @BiTinerary namedtuple or dict or csv-like, i am confused

Comment: post the output you want in the question, please.

Comment: @宏杰李 "you mean before row1, you need a list contain the table's header?" Yes, correct.

Comment: @wcrasta got it

Comment: posted the desired output. Reviewed your edited answer and it seems like you are running into the same problem as I am. Not all the header values are displayed.

Comment: @wcrasta the header's html code is not consistent, the tags are separated, can this be hard coded?

Comment: that is what I feared. Thanks for trying though.