# web scraping espn fantasy bs4 find returns nonetype

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hey relatively new to python here, trying out my first web scraping project on some fantasy football data. I keep running into the same problem in which I cannot find the table data when using bs4. Ive searched all over google, and the only helpful link so far is this one:
[Python - Using BeautifulSoup to scrape an ESPN table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254231/python-using-beautifulsoup-to-scrape-an-espn-table).
So I tried to adapt my code to what he uses for fantasy basketball(which works fine) but still got NoneType. heres the code:

```
import requests, bs4
url = 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/freeagency?leagueId=1613008&seasonId=2017'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find(id = "playertable_0")
#rows = table.find_all(class_=["tableBody sortableRow"])
#rows = iter(rows)
#for row in rows:
#    data = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td') if td.text]
#    print(data)
print type(table)
```

Commented out some of the code for now. I cant seem to figure out why it works when I scrape that guys fantasy basketball table but wont work on my fantasy football one. Hope I asked that right thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not working is that when beautiful soup loads up the web page it is presented with a login form. You are able to see the page with your browser because you have already logged into ESPN but BeautifulSoup cannot.

#### Possible Solution

I would recommend using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) to load the website, sign in, and then go to the page you want to scrape. I am almost certain that BeautifulSoup cannot.

Here are some resources that may assist in using selenium:

- [Selenium Docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
- [Webscraping with Selenium](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/)